# Python spacing around parentheses

Tags: python

Im trying to remove the parenthesis around what is being printed.

Here is my print function

```
print("The text contains", totalChars, "alphabetic characters of which", numberOfe, "(", percent_with_e, "%)", "are 'e'.")
```

It prints like this

```
The text contains 5 alphabetic characters of which 5 ( 100.0 %) are 'e'.
```

But I need it to print like this

```
The text contains 5 alphabetic characters, of which 5 (100.0%) are 'e'.
```

The only difference seems to be the spacing around the parentheses. I cant get the space to be removed from the beginning.

Comment: It sounds like you need string formatting.

Answer (score 5):

An easier way would be to use a format string:

```
 print(f"The text contains {totalChars} alphabetic characters, of which {numberOfe} ({percent_with_e}%) are 'e'")
```

Which is a newer way to accomplish the old format method:

```
print("The text contains {} alphabetic characters, of which {} ({}%) are 'e'".format(totalChars, numberOfe, percent_with_e))
```

If you want to continue with the commas, you'll need the `sep` keyword argument:

```
print("The text contains ", totalChars, " alphabetic characters of which ", numberOfe, " (", percent_with_e, "%) ", "are 'e'.", sep="")
```

Comment: In 2020 i think it's almost a crime to use any formatting over f strings.
This makes example code this:
```print(f"The text contains {totalChars} alphabetic characters, of which {numberOfe} ({percent_with_e}%) are 'e'")```

Answer (score 1):

You can better control the inter parameter spacing (print uses a default single space) if you use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print("The text contains {} alphabetic characters\
       of which {} ({}%) are 'e'.".format(totalChars, numberOfe, percent_with_e))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do it with `format` just don't supply them as different arguments (for which the default `sep` of `' '` is used).

That is, transform the `percent_with_e` to a `str` and join with `+`:

```
print("The text contains", totalChars, "alphabetic characters of which", numberOfe, "(" + str(percent_with_e) + "%)", "are 'e'.")
```

Or, with `format`:

```
s = "The text contains {} alphabetic characters of which {} ({}) are 'e'".format(totalChars, numberOfe, percent_with_e)

print(s)
The text contains 5 alphabetic characters of which 5 (100.0) are 'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with the print formatting. When passing multiple arguments to the print function, it automatically inserts spaces. If you want to format the string, the best way is to use the '%' operator.

```
percent = "(%d%%)" % percent_with_e
print("The text contains", totalChars, "alphabetic characters of which", numberOfe, percent, "are 'e'.")
```